# AzureDevops Connection Permission for Cycling Service Principal Secret

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, devops

I am trying to create a release in AzureDevops that checks the expiration of SP secrets and then updates them if necessary. I have the part that does the check:

```
 param (
    [string]$SpId  
)
$SpSecret 
$SpEndDate = az ad sp credential list --id $SpId --query "[].{Key:endDate}" -o tsv

((Get-Date $SpEndDate).AddDays(-30) -lt (Get-Date)) {
    #Set a new secret value if it is about to expire
    $SpSecret = az ad sp credential reset --name $SpId --query password -o tsv   
}

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=var01;Secret=true]$SpSecret"

Write-Host $env:Secret
```

The issue now is that the service connection does not have the permissions to run "z ad sp credential reset". I have looked at the connection and don't see a permission that will work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are the permissions of the service principal running the pipeline ? you can check that from your azure activie directory. It needs this api permission: `
Application.ReadWrite.All` oor at least `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` if the service principals has been created by this other service princilpal

Comment: OwnedBy would probably be better + add the SP as owner

Comment: Is `az ad sp credential list` working in your script? What exact error do you get?

Comment: I have been out of the office and will check your reply tomorrow. Looks like what I need and I will mark as answer if so. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the Azure Resource Manager service connection to use the `AzureCLI`, the system will create an AD App for you automatically, check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-rm-endpoint?view=azure-devops#what-happens-when-you-create-a-resource-manager-service-connection).
 If you use this service connection with `AzureCLI`, it will use the credential of the service principal of the AD App in your tenant. For the concept of service principal and AD App, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals).

To fix the issue, navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `App registrations` -> `All applications` -> find the application corresponding to the service connection, its name should be like `organizationname-projectname-513f22f1-befd-xxxxxxcfe90f1`. Then click it -> add the permission like the screenshots(**Note**: your user account need the admin role to click the **`Grant admin consent`** button, e.g. `Global admin` ).

[image]

[image]

After granting the permission, wait for a while, the service principal of the service connection will be able to create the AD App, the Azure CLI task should work fine.

---

The `Application.ReadWrite.All` permission will allow the service principal to create, read, update and delete all applications and service principals. If you want to avoid the security problem, you can also use the powershell to add the service principal of the service connection as an `Owner` to the service principal which you want to reset credential. Then just need to add `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` permission in the screenshot above.

Navigate to the `organizationname-projectname-513f22f1-befd-xxxxxxcfe90f1` app in the portal -> click the `Managed application in local directory` as below.

[image]

Then copy the `Object ID` in the screenshot.

[image]

Then use the powershell below(At least you need to be the `Owner` of the target App to run the command).

```
Add-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId <ObjectId of the app which corresponding to the service principal> -RefObjectId <ObjectId of the service connection corresponding service principal>
```

**Besides**: At first, I suppose `Add-AzureADServicePrincipalOwner` is enough, but per my test, it does not work, looks may be `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` does not allow to operate on the service principal corresponding to the AD App.

Comment: The top portion will work once I have an administrator to run the permissions. They may be hesitant to do that due to the security implications.  

When I attempt to run the powershell you suggested I get this error:  

Message: Resource <objectId> does not exist or one of its queried reference-property
objects are not present.  

I tried instead to use the CLI command  

`az ad app owner add --id --owner-object-id`

and I got the same result.  

any ideas?

Comment: @AaronL. In `Add-AzureADApplicationOwner`, make sure the `-ObjectId` is the objectId of the AD App(App registration) corresponding to the service principal, not the objectId of the service principal itself, and `-RefObjectId` is the objectId of the service connection service principal, not its AD App. It should work.